# Can't delete polygon

Tags: qgis

[image]I drew a polygon, and then went to delete the layer I drew it in, but it didn't delete the polygon. I know have a random red shape that isn't attached to any of my layers in the middle of my project. Even if I disable all the layers, the shape remains. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: How did you drew the polygon ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you still have it identified.

Choose the identify tool and click somewhere else, the red outline should disappear.

Edit based on comments:

With the picture now, it looks like an unfinished polygon. So when you are editing, and start creating a polygon and never right click to finish it. It is saved until you return to editing that layer. Save the project and restart QGIS, that should remove it.

Comment: You're right. I suspected the same, quite a common "mistake".

Comment: I tried that, it just selects something else and nothing happens to the polygon

Comment: With the picture now, it looks like an unfinished polygon. So when you are editing, and start creating a polygon and never right click to finish it. It is saved until you return to editing that layer. Save the project and restart QGIS, that should remove it.

Comment: Restarting QGIS got rid of it, can't believe I didn't try that myself! Thank you :)

Comment: Always a good first option :D But yeah, sometimes you can get the leftover artifacts from unfinished editing. Glad it helped.

Comment: Usually you can fix this issue without restarting QGIS. Just start drawing a new feature in any polygon layer. The leftover unfinished polygon will either become active and allow you to continue drawing it, or it will disappear. Right click to finish drawing, and hit escape to discard it.