# Deleting polygon created with Add Polygon Feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, delete

I was playing with the "Add polygon Feature" in QGIS. I ended up with some weird ugly polygon. How do I delete the polygon?

[image: Weird polygon]

Comment: FYI, all the green X's are places where the polygon boundary intersects itself, which is invalid geometry. If you create a polygon with self-intersections, it will cause lots of errors later.

Comment: To understand rollback and de-duplication on this question see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/how-do-i-act-when-my-answer-gets-accepted-but-does-not-answer-the-actual-proble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select your polygon you wish to delete [image] on the canvas or attribute table, then press the red trash bin [image] or alternatively delete key on your keyboard. Make sure editing mode is enabled [image] when doing this. Otherwise the red trash bin is greyed out.

Comment: I tried it, but without success.

https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqXZoyU4bS

Comment: @kabouter Ah I see. You polygon already is deleted. Thats a graphical issue. I remember there were several questions about this here on GIS SE, but I cannot find them at the moment.

Comment: @kabouter finally found at least one of them: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339298/cant-delete-polygon/339299#339299 If this does not fix your issue and you cannot find the other questions about this, I suggest to edit your question and include these details